# Handle HelpButton Click Event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've recently been messing around with the help button in which you can add to windows form title bar by simply doing the following:

```
frm.MaximizeBox = false;
frm.MinimizeBox = false;
frm.HelpButton = true;
```

THE problem is that I'm trying to catch the click event of when this HelpButton is clicked AND then display a `MessageBox()`, I've looked into `_HelpButtonClicked`but haven't been able to get it working properly (if someone could show a example of that, that would be helpful).

I've tried picking up the click event the same way that you would use when catching the click event of a normal button, but this hasn't worked. Here is a example shown below of what I've tried, the problem is that it DOESN'T work, when HelpButton is pressed the `MessageBox()` does NOT pop up:

```
    frm.MaximizeBox = false;
    frm.MinimizeBox = false;
    frm.HelpButton = true;
    frm.HelpButton.Click += HelpButtonClicked;

    static void HelpButtonClicked()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Help Button Clicked");//Doesn't work :(
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Firstly, what is the *exact* problem you're seeing? Does it not compile? or does the text box now appear during execution?

Comment: @GEEF The problem is that the message box doesn't appear at all.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for updating the question. The code looks like WinForms, so if that is the case you may consider adding the WinForms tag to the question :)

Comment: Your code does not compile. Please **copy+paste** code from your IDE, do not write it out from memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your form should handle the [HelpButtonClicked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.helpbuttonclicked(v=vs.110).aspx) event *(not a button named HelpButton)*:

```
frm.HelpButtonClicked += HelpButtonClicked;

static void HelpButtonClicked(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Help Button Clicked");//Works :)
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Works perfectly.

Comment: Hi, where can I write this part of code? in my Form.cs?

Comment: @mikesneider It could be anywhere. If you want to be in your form code, just replace `frm.` with `this.`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are attempting to use the bool property to wire up the event.

You need to use: 
Form.HelpButtonClicked

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.helpbuttonclicked(v=vs.110).aspx